# get path from directory structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get the path from a specific directory structure like the one on the image,
 if I click on *chile>citrus>orange*  i need to use that "*chile/citrus/orange*" as a path so i can create subdirectories there. I tried to save every text of the element span on an array but it didn't work.

[image: file structure]

the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var files = <?php echo json_encode($folders); ?>;
    var file_tree = build_file_tree(files);
    file_tree.appendTo('#files');


    function build_file_tree(files) {

        var tree = $('<ul>');

        for (x in files) {

            if (typeof files[x] == "object") {
                var span = $('<span class="nombre">').html(x).appendTo(
                    $('<li>').appendTo(tree).addClass('folder')
                );
                var subtree = build_file_tree(files[x]).hide();
                span.after(subtree);
                span.click(function() {
                    $(this).parent().find('ul:first').toggle();
                });

            } else {
                $('<li>').html(files[x]).appendTo(tree).addClass('file').click(function(){
                    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");return false;})
               //The click() function in the line above is where my links for download should be but I am unsure of what to do from here.

            }

        }

        return tree;

    }
    });  

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a jQuery fan, and I don't really have any experience in it because of that, so I'll try to answer your question with pure javascript. This will generate variable `pathToFile`, which is the path to the file in the format `parent/child/innerchild`. You can do whatever processing you want with the file path to create the link yourself. You should put this inside of the `click()` function. <strike>**EDIT:** Also make sure to set the variable `isFolder` to if it should be finding a path for a folder. If it needs to find a path for a folder, set it to true. If not, set it to false.</strike> It now automatically detects if it's finding a path to a folder or just a file and acts accordingly. Here goes:

```
var parts=[$(this).get(0).textContent];
for(var curParent=($(this).get(0).classList.contains('nombre')?($(this).get(0).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode):($(this).get(0).parentNode.parentNode));
    curParent.tagName.toLowerCase()!=='div';
    curParent=curParent.parentNode.parentNode
){
    parts.push(curParent.querySelector('.nombre').textContent);
}
parts.reverse();
var pathToFile=parts.join('/');
```

Essentially, it takes the current file (an `<li class="file">`), finds it's parent's parent (an `<li class="folder">`), find's the `<span class="nombre">` inside of it, and adds the span's text content to `parts` (an array of all the names of the folders). Then, it continues this until it has gone all the way to the top of the file structure!

<strike>**EDIT:**

It should now work with folders if you set the `isFolder` variable to true before running this code whenever it needs to find path for folder</strike>
It should now be able to automatically detect if it's finding a path to a folder or just to a file, so you shouldn't need to set any variables anymore

Note that it is untested. I will be happy to fix it if it doesn't work. If it doesn't work, please tell me what happens and any errors in the console.

I hope I've helped!

Comment: Thanks Marka , I tested your code and it was near success. i click my way down chile->citrus->orange , first click on chile outputs 'chile/chile' , second click on citrus outputs'chile/blueberries/citrus' , third click on orange outputs 'chile/blueberries/clementina/orange' , I didn't clicked on  neither blueberries nor clementina.

Comment: ok. Sorry, it was only made to work when you clicked on a file. I will edit it to try to make it also work for if you click on a folder. Meanwhile, you can try to click on a file and see if it outputs the right thing. Thanks!

Comment: ok Fixed it. It was a very small issue. Right now it's very crude, I'll try to fix it up soon

Comment: Not so crude anymore, in fact it's now fully automated! It will automatically detect if it's finding path for file or for folder and will do the correct thing

Answer (score 0):

would a php only solution work for you?

```
    function list_directories($dir){

        $temp_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$dir;

        if (is_link($dir)) {
            echo "do nothing";
        } else {

            $pattern = '/./';
            $bad = array(".", "..", ".DS_Store", "Thumbs.db", ".svn", ".git");

            $class = 'dir';
            $contents = scandir($temp_dir,1);
            $files = array_diff($contents, $bad);
            krsort($files);

            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($files as $item){
                $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($item,"."),1)); 
                echo "<li><a href='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$dir.$item."'>".$item."</a></li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: They aren't literally existing directories, just a tree on the webpage itself.

Comment: oh, you mean you want to create the directories if the link is clicked and your $folders is an array you made up arbitrarily?

Comment: hi, all directories exist, if i get 1 orange order I must create a subfolder called" shipment01" inside the orange folder, i need the path of the last folder where my new shipment01 folder(chile/citrus/orange/) will reside.

Comment: in that case you do need to stick to php (or whatever server side language). You can expand my code to append directories on demand, but  at this point I should ask, what is the purpose of creating all these directories? What will happen when you have 100 million shippments? shouldn't you consider a DB solution instead?

Comment: you're right! in the future there might be so many directories in every fruit folder. and every shipment folder will contain at least 10 files. this is just a quick momentary solution. Later a Db solution will be evaluated.